# How to parallelize a for loop in python that contains a post request API call?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, request

I have a very large data set (71M rows - ~7GB csv file) that I have loaded into a data-frame in pandas.

I need to send each row in the data frame in a post request call to an API, and then store the response into another data-frame which is exported later and analyzed

Currently my code looks like this

```
##read data from csv

for row in data.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    ##There is an if-else ladder to create a header depending on the type of values in a row

    ##Code to create a json payload

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    t = json.loads(r.text)

    ## A try and except block to add the data sent via header and payload + the response from API call back into a new data-frame. (exception is in case there is no response from the API)

##write the data back to csv
```

The API can handle a QPS (queries per sec) of about 50,000 plus, however this method of executing just hits it with roughly 11 QPS. In my previous test, I split a smaller set of data (about 7M rows) 4 times,and ran 4 different Jupyter notebooks with the same code , so effectively reaching a QPS of about 44-50 and ran the code for 24 hours.

**Note**: I don't wish to hit it with that much QPS as it is a production API , I've been given an allowance of about 10k QPS

Since I now need to run it on a much larger set, is there a way this can be done in Python? Is splitting the data into 4 chunks and running them together equivalent to processing the code in parallel ?

Maybe I am going about this all wrong and there is some other way ? - my experience with python is mainly for analytics and data science work (numpy, pandas etc) - so this was the only approach that came to my mind.

I'm using a system with Intel xenon e5-2690 v2 processor (20 cores) and 128 GB RAM, so I think it ought to be capable to handle this since in my previous execution, it hardly broke a sweat in terms of resource utilization.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
All the suggestions pointed me to aiohttp, however because I was running out of time, and I had made headway with multiprocessing's pool I went ahead with that. Added a few extra lines of code

```
if __name__=='__main__':

##read data

data_split = np.array_split(data,20)

p = Pool(20)
p.map(apicall, data_split)
```

The '*apicall*' function is essentially the same as above bit of code (the for loop section)

It runs fine for about a dataset of 10,000. However if I scale it up to 100,000 or more, I get an error and I get stuck again

> OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

**Edit2:**
Understood why I was getting the above error. Looks like async is the only way to go.

Comment: can you take a look at async in python

Comment: i second InAFlash's comment. especially [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) may help.

Comment: I couldn't really figure out how to use aiohttp, so used multiprocessing instead and basically added 

p = Pool(20)
p.map(apicall, data_split)

The program works fine for a load of 10,000 rows, it performs as expect (1/20th of the time running in a single thread) 

However, if I scale that up to say even 100,000 rows, I get a WindowsOS error

OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

and I'm stuck because I'm not using any port in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is your tool to go.

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) as resp:
        resp = await resp.text()
```

Comment: So i tried this bit of code, and I got a syntax error which upon research told me it has to be in an async def function. So now I have 

async def some_function(url,payload,headers):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) as resp:
            resp = await resp.text()
            print(resp)

and in my main for loop, i have 

t=some_function(url,payload,headers)

This gives me an error - coroutine 'some_function' was never awaited

If i use t= await some_function(url,payload,headers)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)

It has two benefits :

- if your dataset is too large to fit in RAM, Dask will handle this problem for you
- Dask will help you to parallelize your requests.